# Defining $\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{j}A,\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{k} B,p:\text{Ker }c\to \text{Ker }f,q:\text{Im }c\to \text{Im }f,$ using elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, morphism

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Suppose I have a linear transformation or homomorphism map $f:A\to B,$ where $A,B$ can be groups, rings or modules. If I have the following two sequences of maps:

$\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{j}A\xrightarrow{\sharp}A/\text{Ker }f\quad (*)$

$\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{k} B\xrightarrow{}B/\text{Im }f\quad (**)$

and a commutative square, with $a,c,d$ are all either linear transformations/homomorphic maps with $A,A',B,B'$ are either groups, rings, vector spaces or modules:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A' & \xrightarrow{a} & A  \\
c\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow f   \\
B' & \xrightarrow{d} & B \\
\end{array},\quad (***)$$

From the above commutative square, I have the following two linear transformations/homomorphic maps:  $p:\text{Ker }c\to \text{Ker }f$ and $q:\text{Im }c\to \text{Im }f.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

What I would like to know is how do I describe the argument and image in terms of elements for the maps:

$\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{j}A,\quad (1)$

$\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{k} B,\quad (2)$

$p:\text{Ker }c\to \text{Ker }f,\quad (3)$ and

$q:\text{Im }c\to \text{Im }f.\quad (4)$

For $(1),$  if $a\in \text{Ker }f,$ then $f(a)=0.$ Do the map $j$ in terms of elements is defined as: $a\mapsto j(a):=f(a)\mapsto j(f(a)):=0\mapsto j(0)?$

for $(2),$ if $b\in \text{Im }f,$ then $\exists a \in A, f(a)=b.$ Do the map $k$ in terms of elements is defined as: $b\mapsto k(b):=f(a)\mapsto k(f(a))?$

for $(3),$ again, if $a'\in \text{Ker }c,$ then the map $p$ in terms of elements is defined as:

$a'\mapsto p(a'):=c(a')\mapsto p(c(a')):=0\mapsto p(0).$ But $p(0)\in \text{Ker }f.$ So $p(c(a'))=p(0)=0=f(p(0))=f(p(c(a')))?$

for $(4)$ if $b'\in \text{Im}c,$ then $b=c(a'), a'\in A'.$ The map $q$ in terms of elements is defined as: $b'\mapsto q(b'):=c(a')\mapsto q(c(a')).$  But since $q(c(a'))\in  \text{Im }f,$ there exists an $a\in A$ so that $q(c(a'))=f(a).$ Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin for the maps $p$, when you say $f$ restrict to $\text{Ker }c,$ then you compose it with $j$, in terms of elements, what does that look like?  Similarly for the map $q$ when the map $d$ restricts to $\text{Im }c.$  I made this post as a follow up to another post I made last night.  I am learning about exact sequences for modules, and the notations for these four maps amongs others I am seeing quite a bit of.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin also, can't $j\circ (f|_{\text{Ker }c})$ and $d|_{\text{Im }c}$ be made more explicit in terms of elements when i plug in something in $p$ and $q$ respectively.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i thought when i have an element $a\in \text{Ker }f,$  I have to take the evaluated form from $f$ before plugging bak into $j$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do know what an inclusion map is.  I just did not know I can treat $j$ and $k$ as inclusion maps.  But what about for maps $p$ and $q.$  If I have $a'\in \text{Ker }c,$ and $b'\in \text{Im }c,$ then is $p(a')=j(f(a'))$ and $q(b')=d(b')$?

Comment: comments removed in light of answer typed.

Comment: Some of the things you write do not work for arbitrary groups/group homomorphisms or rings/ring homomorphisms. Expanding my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that some of the things you write (in the generality you try to state them in) don't work...

Anyway: if you have a commutative diagram of functions (whether morphisms of algebraic structures or just functions)
$$\begin{array}{rcl} A' & \stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow} & A  \\
{\scriptstyle c}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow {\scriptstyle f}   \\
B' & \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\end{array}$$
then it is necessarily the case that $d(\mathrm{Im}(c))\subseteq \mathrm{Im}(f)$: because if $b'\in\mathrm{Im}(c)$, then there exists $r\in A'$ such that $c(r)=b'$. Then $d(b') = d(c(r)) = f(a(r))\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$.

So if we restrict $d$ to $\mathrm{Im}(c)$, we get a map whose image is inside $\mathrm{Im}(f)$. So $d$ induces a map $q\colon\mathrm{Im}(c)\to\mathrm{Im}(f)$.

In the case where we are working with groups, or modules, or rings, so that the notion of "kernel" makes sense, if $x\in\mathrm{ker}(c)$, then $a(x)\in\ker(f)$. Because we have that (using $0$ to represent the identity element in the case of groups):
$$f(a(x)) = d(c(x)) = d(0) = 0.$$

So $a(\ker(c)) \subseteq \ker(f)$, and therefore $a$ induces a map $p\colon\ker(c)\to\ker(f)$ which sends $x\in\ker(c)$ to $a(x)$.

$j$ is the inclusion map $\ker(f)\hookrightarrow A$.

$k$ is the inclusion map $\mathrm{Im}(f)\hookrightarrow B$.

So $p\colon \ker c\to\ker f$ is the restriction of $a$ to $\ker(c)$. Alternatively, it is the composition of the inclusion map $\ker(c)\hookrightarrow A'$ with $a$.

And $q\colon\mathrm{Im}(c)\to\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is the restriction of $d$ to $\mathrm{Im}(c)$. Alternatively, it is the composition of the inclusion $\mathrm{Im}(c)\hookrightarrow B'$ with $d$.

All  of these maps have obvious formulas, where necessary in terms of $a$ and $d$.

Note that you also mention maps $A\to A/\ker(f)$ and $B\to B/\mathrm{Im}(f)$. The first map makes sense in the case of abelian groups, modules, vector spaces, groups, and rings, because you can always take a quotient modulo the kernel of a homomorphism. But the map $B\to B/\mathrm{Im}(f)$ does not make sense in that generality: it makes sense for abelian groups, modules, and vector spaces (because you can take the quotient modulo any subgroup/submodule/subspace).  But they do not necessarily make sense in the setting of groups or rings, as the image of a group under a group homomorphism $A\to B$ need not be a normal subgroup of $B$; and the image of a ring homomorphism $A\to B$ is not generally an ideal (and in the case of unital rings with unital morphisms, it is *never* an ideal unless $f$ is surjective...)

Comment: so for the map $p,$ I would have a map $w:a\to \text{ker }c,$ and $j:\text{ker }c\hookrightarrow A',$ and so $p=w\circ j.$ Similarly for the map $q,$ I have $t:d \to  \text{Im } c,$ and $d:\text{Im }c\hookrightarrow B'.$ Then $q=t\circ d?$

Comment: @Seth $a$ is the name of a function in your diagram, it should not be the name of a set that will be the domain of $w$. $d$ is the name of a function in your diagram, so it should not be the name of a set that will be the domain of a new function $t$. I **said** what $p$ is:  it is the restriction of $a$ to $\ker(c)$. Why are you defining a new map $w$ ?  Is  it just so that you can confuse yourself *just* a little more?   I said what $q$ is: it is the restriction of $d$ to $\mathrm{Im}(c)$. So why are you introducing a new map $t$? Is it just so that you can  confuse yourself even more?

Comment: sorry, you mean then $p=a|_{\text{Ker }c}\circ j$ and $q=d|_{\text{Im }c }?$  But for $a|_{\text{Ker }c},$ in terms of evaluating at elements, what does $a|_{\text{Ker }c}\circ j$ look like?

Comment: I mean $p=a|_{\ker c}$, which interestingly enough is exactly what I said. "$a|_{\ker c}\circ j$" doesn't make sense, because the codomain of $j$ is $A$, and the domain of $a$ is $A'$. You cannot compose $j$ with $a$.

Comment: I think the first time when i saw your deleted post, i saw $a$ sends to the restriction of $\text{Ker }c$ and $p=a\circ j.$ Then I saw another post where you said there was a typo.  I wasn't sure what you were referring to.  In the case of $a|_{\text{Ker }c},$ that just means $p=a(a'),$ where $a'\in \text{Ker }c?$ or does it mean $a\in \text{Ker }c$  I am not sure if by $a$, you mean $a$ as an element or $a$ as a map in the above commutative diagram?

Comment: I deleted the comments, and I posted the answer, which can be edited in case of inadvertent errors. So you should reference the answer. Yes, the restriction of a function $g$ to a subset of its domain is just what $g$ does, but to the elements of the subset only. Surely you know what the restriction of a function is.

Comment: I am more familar with the notation $p|_{\text{Ker }c}(a)=p(a).$  Is that what you meant by $p=a|_{\text{Ker }c}?$

Comment: then the inclusion map $j$ composing with $p$ gives $(p|_{\text{Ker}c }\circ j )(a)=(p\circ j)(a)?$

Comment: $p|_{\ker c}(a)$ is the value of the function $p|_{\ker c}$ at the point $a$. $p$ is a function. $a$ is a function. $a|_{\ker c}$ is a function obtained by restricting $a$ to $\ker c$. The domain of $p$ is $\ker c$, so it doesn't make much sense to "restrict" $p$ to its full domain, which amounts to doing nothing at all, but with five extra symbols just to confuse the enemy, perhaps...

Comment: $p|_{\ker c}$ is using lots of notation to say nothing, given that the domain of $p$ is *already* $\ker c$. Composing $j$ with $p$ is $p\circ j$.

Comment: so $p$ is a composition of function $a$ with the inclusion map $j$ where the domain of $a$ is restrict to $\text{Ker }c?$ Similarly for functon $q,$ where it is a composition of the inclusion map $k$ with the function $d$ where the domain of $d$ is restricted to $\text{Im }c?$

Comment: @Seth: Let $g\colon X\to Y$ be **any** function, and let $Z\subseteq X$. By definition, the restriction to $g$ to $Z$ is $g|_{Z} = g\circ \iota$, where $\iota\colon Z\to X$ is the inclusion map from $Z$ to $X$. Again: this is just  about functions, at a set level. I don't understand why you insist on tying yourself into knots over this.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: for maps like $\text{Ker }c \to \text{Ker }f,$ $\text{Im }c \to \text{Im }f,$ and $\text{coKer }c \to \text{coKer }f,$  can they be written using composition of maps from the commutative square above?  I often seen question about exact sequences of modules/groups, etc just say such and such maps are monomorphisms/epimorphisms or injective/surjective, and show another map is either injective/surjective.  When I first saw the notation, i was having trouble trying to describe it in terms of elements.

Comment: it seems that it is enough that $a(\ker(c)) \subseteq \ker(f)$ for $a$ to induce the map $p.$   How come is only a subset and not a equality? I mean if we have equality  $a(\ker(c)) =\ker(f)$ what would that imply?

Comment: We don't have equality because $a$ need not be surjective, and even if it is, there is no reason why something that lies in the kernel of $f$ needs to be the image of something in the kernel of $a$. Why would it?. Are you spending *any* time thinking through these instead of just jumping into asking? What if all the maps are the zero maps; Do you have $a(\ker(c))=\ker(f)$ in that case? The equality implies... pretty much *nothing* other than that there is equality.

Comment: I am just surprised we only need the subset relation instead of equality for inducing a map.  That is all.  I am just wondering if we have equality, does one get to say more about these maps.

Comment: also, this is the first time seeing if $a(\ker(c)) \subseteq \ker(f),$ then that means $a$ can induce a map.....  I seen in a lot of isomorphism theorems where we have a the kernel of one function is a subset of another function's kernel. But I just thought that is some condition for the theorem to hold and nothing beyond that.

Comment: @Seth This has **nothing** to do with isomorphisms. This is *basic properties of functions*. You are getting tripped up at the level of **functions from one set to another**. If $f\colon X\to Y$ is **any** function, $A$ is a subset of $X$, $B$ is a subset of $Y$, and $f(A)\subseteq B$, then you **automatically** get a function $A\to B$ by using the function $f$. That is **the only thing at work** in that "induces a function". Nothing to do with isomorphism theorems, kernels, or anything else. It's **just** about what functions **do**.

Comment: thank you for telling me that.  I really appreciate it.